# Complicated background drawable android

Tags: android, combobox, background, scale, layer

I want to make complicated background for spinner(combobox) with xml. for example 
 one rectangle in half left and other half will be divided to three parts, in the middle one there will be one triangle. since my spinner width and height are completely  dynamic ,how I can position these shapes based on percentage of width and height
Thanks

Comment: you can't do it in XML, however you can create a custom Drawable and draw everything in draw() method

Answer (score 0):

try giving weights they act like percentage

```
  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <Button
        android:text="test"
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        weight="1" />

     <Button
        android:text="testing"
        android:id="@+id/testing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        weight="1" />

  </LinearLayout>
```